# React useState causes performance issues - the proper way to handle menu interaction

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an app with a "menu". The "menu" is fairly complex, and the user can open small divs to set parameters that affect the app in real time. The app is structured as below:

```
Parent div with multiple useState instances to set parameters
    - Menu Child Div 
        - functions to set those state variables are all passed to this div
        - parent state is altered using these 
    - Main div where the results are displayed 
        - receives the state from the parent div and displays appropriately
```

The way that it works is that when the user interacts with the menu, the state is altered in the parent and that state change is then passed in the props to the main child div. This is causing performance issues as the app has to rerender everything when something changes in the menu and the existence of so many state variables may be a problem.

What is the best way to handle this? Using the useReducer function instead could be an option, but I am not sure that this alone would solve the problem. How do I make the main div respond to changes in the menu without everything having to be rerendered?

How do you handle interaction between your menus and your main div without having to re render everything?

Would the performance issues be solved by doing the following?

```
Parent div does not address state
    - Menu Child Div 
        - interacts with redux state to change options
    - Main div where the results are displayed 
        - reads in and reacts to redux changes
```

Comment: can you share som ecode with us? 
you can pass an array as second argument to the useEffect hook to only run the effect when that changes: 

    useEffect(() => {
      document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
    }, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes

Answer (score 0):

If you want a React component not to re-render unless the local state/props are changed, you may consider replacing your React.Component with React.PureComponent.

Whenever you're dealing with State that is being passed around between component orders, you may want to consider managing a global store. You can do this by using tools such as Redux, MobX-State-Tree, or Context API. This is especially useful if you're managing a mid-large scale project.

Resources:

https://ozmoroz.com/2018/09/what-is-purecomponent/

This resource has some great info on common React tools:

https://www.reactnative.express

And of course, there is always React's docs of which you are likely well aware of:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html